# Create a constraint for Bottom Layout guide in a XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I’m updated an app that was built using XIB’s.  In one of the XIB’s I have the view then some objects inside, one being a tableview.  I put a constraint for the bottom and it lists like so:

```
Bottom Space to: Superview
         Equals: 5
```

Depending on the device, the tableview will extend beyond the screen at the bottom, not extend all the way & sometimes lines up just right.  Out of curiosity I created a test project that uses stroyboards(which I have more experience with) & I created the same scenario but being that the View Controller Scene uses Top & Bottom Layout guides my constraint for the bottom looks like so:

```
Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide
         Equals: 5
```

This works perfectly on all devices; the tableview lines up with the bottom of the screen.
So my question is how do I get the same constraint in my XIB to line up to the bottom if I don’t have a Bottom Layout Guide as an option?

[image]

Comment: did you add the constraint in the correct size class (e.g. any/any)!?

Comment: I'm using Size Classes

Comment: The question is if you did set the constraints in the correct class, if you set them just in Compact/Any, they will not occur on the devices that dont fit that category.

Comment: I've always set it to wAny hAny. If I change it to wAny hRegular, nothing changes.  What's even more confusing is that in Preview it looks the way I want for all iPhones, but when I run in different simulators it does not.

Answer (score 0):

To set `UITableView` constraints as like below code so it will occupied whole screen.

```
Leading Space = 5 from mainView
Top Space = 5 from mainView
Bottom Space = 5 from mainView 
Trailing Space = 5 from mainView
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: If I Ctrl drag from tableview to my on parent view & select Bottom Space to container I get the same constraint: Bottom Space to: Superview

Comment: @KFP, are you able to upload screenshot of your constraint? and your output. if you have not any concern.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't getting anywhere with this approach, so I added a storyboard, added my objects and everything is lining up accordingly.  I don't know if this is a bug or something, but I've never had this problem before.  thanks to everyone for there help.